# How can I hide a row in another Excel sheet with a ToggleButton?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that I want to put an active X control, the result I expect is to hide a row in another sheet when I click the button and then unhide if I click the button again.

Here is the code I've tried.

```
Private Sub PLK08_Click()
    Dim MyC As String
    MyC = Worksheets("stepcleaning").Rows("A12")

    If PLK08.Value Then
        Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(MyC).Hidden = True
    Else
        Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(MyC).Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

the result I expect is to hide a row in another sheet when I click the button and then unhide if I click the button again

Comment: Don't use `ActiveSheet` instead specify a worksheet like `Worksheets("SheetWhereTheRowShouldBeHidden").Rows(MyC).Hidden = True` • Also what type of control is `PLK08`? If it is a button then what do you expect `PLK08.Value` should do? Or is it a ToggleButton? • Please tell us more about *which* row  in *which* sheet should be hidden?

Comment: Also, instead of the `If` statement, you can assign `PLK08.Value` to the `Hidden` attribute for your target row.

Comment: PLK08.value is a togglebutton, and the thing I want it to be hidden is row A12 of stepcleaning sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This should be all you need.

```
Private Sub PLK08_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("stepcleaning").Rows(12).Hidden = PLK08.Value
End Sub
```

Note that `A12` is a cell while the row number is `12` and the column is `A`. Therefore a `Rows("A12")` does not exist but a `Rows(12)` or `Columns("A")` or `Range("A12")`. So if you want to hide a row it must be `Rows(12)`.